# Custom Composite View Threading Issues Surrounding addView()

Tags: android, view

I've been working on a custom view but am having some serious UI Thread blocking issues when attaching a large number of inflated views to tje custom view (which simply extends a FrameLayout).

While I've tried moving the child view creation from the Main Thread into a background thread, to the point that everything is set up in a thread then a single ViewGroup is added to the activities content view, but the problem with this seems to be that rather than staggering the view laying out and drawing, it is essentially invalidates everything in one go.

Does anyone have any experience of staggering this or have any suggestions how to overcome this issue?

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you post more details so that we can understand why the `View` creation is taking so long?

I don't believe that you can stagger this.  Pre-Honeycomb invalidating a `ViewGroup` caused the entire child hierarchy to re-draw :(

See [this great I/O talk](http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/sessions/accelerated-android-rendering.html) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the response, if nothing can be done, then that is that. I was hoping there would be something a little nifty I could to at least not lock up.